# Select id of div that still has to be made

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code:

```
var infoWindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    content = "<div class=\"row\">"+
        "<h2 class=\"col xs4\">"+name+"</h2>"+
        "<div class=\"col xs2\">"+
            "<div id=\"w108\"></div>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class=\"col xs2\">"+
            "<div id=\"o108\"></div>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class=\"col xs2\">"+
            "<div id=\"c108\"></div>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class=\"col xs2\">"+
            "<div id=\"i108\"></div>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class=\"col xs2\">"+
            "<div id=\"pi108\"></div>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class=\"col xs2\">"+
            "<div id=\"a108\"></div>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class=\"col xs2\">"+
            "<div id=\"bi108\"></div>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class=\"col xs2\">"+
            "<div id=\"dw108\"></div>"+
        "</div>"+
    "</div>";

    infoWindow.setContent(content);

var parent = document.createElement("div"),
    title = document.createElement("h1"),
    t = document.createTextNode(name),
    w = document.getElementById("w108"),
    wChart = new google.charts.Bar(w),
    o = document.getElementById("o108"),
    oChart = new google.charts.Bar(o),
    c = document.getElementById("c108"),
    cChart = new google.charts.Bar(c),
    i = document.getElementById("i108"),
    iChart = new google.charts.Bar(i),
    pi = document.getElementById("pi108"),
    piChart = new google.charts.Bar(pi),
    a = document.getElementById("a108"),
    aChart = new google.charts.Bar(a),
    bi = document.getElementById("bi108"),
    biChart = new google.charts.Bar(bi),
    dw = document.getElementById("dw108"),
    dwChart = new google.charts.Bar(dw);
```

The problem is that when for example `dw = document.getElementById("dw108"), dwChart = new google.charts.Bar(dw)` is called the div isn't made jet. This results in an error:

> Uncaught Error: Container is not defined.

I have already tried to place `infoWindow.setContent(content);` at different lines but that didn't help. Using `setTimeout` around the div selecting variables also failed. So my question is how can I target that div `dw108` while it still needs to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. select the element after it has been added to the DOM (inside a `domready` event listener on the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)

From the documentation:

> domready | Arguments:  None 
>   This event is fired when the  containing the InfoWindow's content is attached to the DOM. You may wish to monitor this event if you are building out your info window content dynamically.

Example:

```
infoWindow.setContent(content);
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, "domready", function() {
    // What needs to be done after domready
});
```

2. create the DOM Element using document.createElement and pass that into the `InfoWindow.setContent` method (that takes a string or a [Node (DOM ELement)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)).

> setContent(content:string|Node)
>   Return Value:  None